# In the C language preprocessor, how to define different branches according to parameters

Tags: c

During preprocessing, how to define different execution processes according to the macro parameters in the macro definition

```
#define LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL 1
#define LOG_LEVEL_ERROR 2

// Basic trace macros
// s is format string like "tx id is : %d"
// p1, p2, p3...p9: values to output
#define TRACE_1(log_level, s, p1)
#define TRACE_2(log_level, s, p1, p2)
#define TRACE_3(log_level, s, p1, p2, p3)
// following is TRACE_4~TRACE_9

/* Define the trace macro of this module based on the basic trace macro
** The requirements is to add the prefix "MODE_A ERROR" to the string of the macro whose log_level is LOG_LEVEL_ERROR in this module
*/
#define MODE_A_TRACE_1(log_level, s, p1)
#define MODE_A_TRACE_2(log_level, s, p1, p2)
#define MODE_A_TRACE_3(log_level, s, p1, p2, p3)
// following is MODE_A_TRACE_4 ~ MODE_A_TRACE_9
```

```
// add the prefix "MODE_A ERROR" to the string of the macro whose log_level is LOG_LEVEL_ERROR
// How to achieve this effect??????=========
#define MODE_A_GET_TRACE_STRING(log_level, s)\
#if log_level == LOG_LEVEL_ERROR\
"MODE_A ERROR "##s\
#else\
s\
#endif

// Take MODE_A_TRACE_1 as an example
#define MODE_A_TRACE_1(log_level, s, p1)\
    TRACE_1(log_level, MODE_A_GET_TRACE_STRING(log_level, s), p1)

// calling and expect result 
MODE_A_TRACE_1(LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, "tx id is : %d", tx_id) // expect output: MODE_A ERROR tx id is : xxx
MODE_A_TRACE_1(LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL, "tx id is : %d", tx_id) // expect output: tx id is : xxx
```

I wrote the code according to the requirements, but it is impossible. I've looked up a lot of topics and know this is not going to work, but how can I achieve it to meet the requirements?

Comment: You cannot use preprocessor directives within a macro expansion. All you have is text substitution, so any logic you don't want to handle at runtime, you must handle by clever expansion. This usually involves prefixing a macro argument with a fixed token, defining macros for the possible expansions, and then concatenating the result of that back with something else.

Comment: Macro expansion is "single pass", you cannot have a macro that defines a macro.  Moreover the # preprocessor delimiter must appear at the start of a line preceded only by whitespace.  The `\` at the end of a line escapes the newline so that the subsequent # is not regarded as on a newline, so not valid.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem.  Your solution is as you say "impossible".  Rather than asking about your solution, ask about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: My requirements is to add the prefix "MODE_A ERROR" to the string of the macro whose log_level is LOG_LEVEL_ERROR in MODUL_A_TRACE_1/2/3.../9. As long as it can meet this requirement and avoid duplication of code, there is no limit to the implementation method. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a kludge that does what you requested. It is generally inadvisable to use such kludges; you should find a better way of achieving the goal:

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL    1
#define LOG_LEVEL_ERROR     2


/*  Define "Message<N>" symbols that will be replaced by the desired prefix
    string.
*/
#define Message1    ""
#define Message2    "MODE_A ERROR "

//  Define a macro to replace a log level with one of the "Message<N>" symbols.
#define MessageFor(log_level)   Message##log_level


#define MODE_A_TRACE_1(log_level, s, p1)    \
    printf(MessageFor(log_level) s "\n", p1)
#define MODE_A_TRACE_2(log_level, s, p1, p2) \
    printf(MessageFor(log_level) s "\n", p1, p2)
#define MODE_A_TRACE_3(log_level, s, p1, p2, p3) \
    printf(MessageFor(log_level) s "\n", p1, p2, p3)


int main(void)
{
    MODE_A_TRACE_1(LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL, "Normal, no prefix, value is %d", 17);
    MODE_A_TRACE_1(LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,  "Error, prefix, value is %d",     42);
}
```

Output:

```
Normal, no prefix, value is 17
MODE_A ERROR Error, prefix, value is 42
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a good idea, I can't find any other better way for now.